# What are our thoughts on questions asking for the laws as they relate to cooking?

Tags: discussion, scope

This generally applies to questions about the laws as they relate to food preparation in commercial kitchens (e.g. restaurants). Here's a recent one: [UK laws regarding consumption of food or beverages in a commercial kitchen?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/79003/uk-laws-regarding-consumption-of-food-or-beverages-in-a-commercial-kitchen)

I looked around on meta and couldn't find anything that addressed this. I suppose that it's infrequent enough we can leave the questions and deal with them on an individual basis but, since we have rules prohibiting questions about the [industry/hospitality](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/are-hospitality-industry-questions-on-topic-here), I thought it might be interesting to discuss.

Other related questions from Meta:

- [How can we tag this question about patenting recipes?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/how-can-we-tag-this-question-about-patenting-recipes)
- [Is "Do restaurants regularly disinfect baskets and trays?" a good question?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/is-do-restaurants-regularly-disinfect-baskets-and-trays-a-good-question)

I suppose this most recent question is pretty similar to the question about baskets and trays.

So, should questions about legal issues relating to cooking and selling food be on topic here? If they are not, it seems they may have a home over on law provided they are sufficiently broad.

Answer (score 4):

I'm kind of inclined to say no, let's not take them. I don't think anyone's ever been wild about these, and food laws are very localized, so people tend to not have the expertise to answer even if they do know something about the topic. They're also not relevant to home cooks, and we've already said that business questions and other non-culinary questions about restaurants are off-topic, so this isn't a huge leap.

And... if they're specific enough about location to be able to answer, I think they're okay on law. Declining to answer questions that we're bad at answering, but sending people to a site that can help them better, seems like a net win anyways.